# Sending an Associative Array thru AJAX and insert into database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, ajax

I have a table with a dynamic number of table rows. I'm trying to put all of these data into an associative array and sent it for insertion to my database thru AJAX. However it doesn't insert into my database.

This is my JS and AJAX

```
$('#submit_button').click(function(){
            var table = $("table tbody"),
                data_array = [],
                counter = 1,
                counter_error = 0;

            table.find('tr').each(function (i) {
                var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
                    category_dropdown = document.getElementById('category_' +counter),
                    category_id = category_dropdown.value;

                //alert(counter_error);
                if(category_id == "0"){
                    alert('All categories should be filled');
                    counter_error++;
                    counter++;
                }
                else if(category_id == "1" || category_id == "4"){
                    var item_dropdown = document.getElementById('items_' +counter),
                        item_id = item_dropdown.value,
                        item_description = $(item_dropdown).find(':selected').text(),
                        quantity = document.getElementById('qty_' + counter).value,
                        jan = document.getElementById('jan_' + counter).value,
                        feb = document.getElementById('feb_' + counter).value,
                        mar = document.getElementById('mar_' + counter).value,
                        apr = document.getElementById('apr_' + counter).value,
                        may = document.getElementById('may_' + counter).value,
                        jun = document.getElementById('jun_' + counter).value,
                        jul = document.getElementById('jul_' + counter).value,
                        aug = document.getElementById('aug_' + counter).value,
                        sep = document.getElementById('sep_' + counter).value,
                        oct = document.getElementById('oct_' + counter).value,
                        nov = document.getElementById('nov_' + counter).value,
                        dec = document.getElementById('dec_' + counter).value,
                        price = document.getElementById('unitprice_' + counter).innerText,
                        totalqty = 0;

                    //alert(item_description);
                    if(quantity == ""){
                        quantity = 0;
                    }    
                    if(jan == ""){
                        jan = 0;
                    }
                    if(feb == ""){
                        feb = 0;
                    }
                    if(mar == ""){
                        mar = 0;
                    }
                    if(apr == ""){
                        apr = 0;
                    }
                    if(may == ""){
                        may = 0;
                    }
                    if(jun == ""){
                        jun = 0;
                    }
                    if(jul == ""){
                        jul = 0;
                    }
                    if(aug == ""){
                        aug = 0;
                    }
                    if(sep == ""){
                        sep = 0;
                    }
                    if(oct == ""){
                        oct = 0;
                    }
                    if(nov == ""){
                        nov = 0;
                    }
                    if(dec == ""){
                        dec = 0;
                    }

                    totalqty = parseInt(jan) + parseInt(feb) + parseInt(mar) + parseInt(apr) + parseInt(may) + parseInt(jun) + parseInt(jul) + 
                        parseInt(aug) + parseInt(sep) + parseInt(oct) + parseInt(nov) + parseInt(dec);

                    //alert(quantity);
                    if(item_id == "0"){
                        alert('Please fill-up all item specifications.');
                        counter_error++;
                    }
                    else if(quantity == "0"){
                        alert('Please specify the amount/quantity for all items');
                        counter_error++;
                    }
                    else if(totalqty != quantity){
                        alert('All unit quantities should be distributed.');
                        counter_error++;
                    }
                    else{
                        //put the row element in an data_array
                        data_array.push({
                            supply_id : item_id,
                            supply_description : item_description,
                            quantity : quantity,
                            price : price,
                            jan : jan,
                            feb : feb,
                            mar : mar,
                            apr : apr,
                            may : may,
                            jun : jun,
                            jul : jul,
                            aug : aug,
                            sep : sep,
                            oct : oct,
                            nov : nov,
                            dec : dec
                        });
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
                else{
                    counter++;
                }
            });

            if(counter_error > 0){
                //do not insert to database
            }
            else{
                //insert to database

                alert(JSON.stringify(data_array));

                //convert data_array to object
                var project_details = $.extend({}, data_array);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url('PPMP_controller/submitPPMP'); ?>",
                    data: { data_array : $.param(project_details) },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert('PPMP submission success!');
                    },
                    error: function(errorw) {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });         
            }
        });
    });
```

This is my controller

```
public function submitPPMP(){
    $data_array = $this->input->post('data_array');
    $values = $this->PPMP_model->submitPPMP($data_array);
    echo json_encode($values);
}
```

This is my model

```
function submitPPMP($data_array){
    $date_format = 'DATE_W3C';

    $date_submitted = standard_date($date_format);
    $data = array(
        'user_id' => 1,
        'date_submitted' => $date_submitted,
        'first_lvl_status' => 0,
        'second_lvl_status' => 0,
        'third_lvl_status' => 0,
        'fourth_lvl_status' => 0,
        'submitted' => 1
    );
    $this->db->insert('project', $data);
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();

    if(is_array($data_array) || is_object($data_array)){
        foreach($data_array as $object){
            $project_details = array(
                'project_id' => $id,
                'supply_id' => $object->supply_id,
                'supply_description' => $object->supply_description,
                'quantity' => $object->quantity,
                'price' => $object->price,
                'jan' => $object->jan,
                'feb' => $object->feb,
                'mar' => $object->mar,
                'apr' => $object->apr,
                'may' => $object->may,
                'jun' => $object->jun,
                'jul' => $object->jul,
                'aug' => $object->aug,
                'sep' => $object->sep,
                'oct' => $object->oct,
                'nov' => $object->nov,
                'dec' => $object->dec
            );
            $this->db->insert('project_details', $project_details);
        }
    }
}
```

The line `$this->db->insert('project', data)` works coz it updates my database with the desired data. But the line `$this->db->insert('project_details', $project_details)` doesn't update my database with the values from my associative array (it doesn't even update at all) even though the AJAX request is a success because it runs the code that comes inside `success:function(data)`.

This is the value of my associative array
[image]

Can someone help me with this coz I'm not sure if my controller/model gets the associative array passed to them from AJAX. But I'm sure that my associative array has values inside it as seend from `alert(JSON.stringify(data_array))` before converting it into an object.

Advance thanks for the help.

BTW, I am using Codeigniter 3.0 as an MVC framework.

Comment: Show your $data_array variable value and check to use $this->db->last_query();

Comment: Your code could use some major refactoring, you have a ton of duplicated logic that could be done with loops

Comment: @DelightedD0D I'm sorry for my messy code. I'm still a beginner in using jQuery, js, and AJAX.
@VairaMuthu I've added the values of my $data_array. Can I ask where can I see the result of `$this->db->last_query()` as I've already added it at the end of my model after the `$this->db->insert('project_details', $project_details);`

Comment: when i `return $this->db->last_query();` it returns the query created by `$this->db->insert('project', $data)` not the `$this->db->insert('project_details', $project_details)`. It seems like the program doesn't run the foreach loop.